# Watir can´t access zk element with z-index>0

Tags: watir, zk

I´m testing a zk application. I´m trying to click an option on combobox by its text.
So I'm not get that bacause thah option is inside a div with z-index=88000.
when I check visibility from that div, returns false.
I tried to change z-index via javascript code for 0.
I used the following code:
`browser.execute_script("document.getElementByClass('z-combobox-pp')[5].style.zIndex='0';")`
but I didn't get it. I got that error:
document.getElementByClassName is not a function (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the z-index issue.

However, the javascript error is occurring because the `getElementByClass` method does not exist. It should be `getElementsByClass` (notice the 's' in 'Elements').

Try changing the z-index with:

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClass('z-combobox-pp')[5].style.zIndex='0';")
```